# Showing that $E_{\alpha}$ and $B_{\alpha}$ is spacelike

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

Lately, I came across the concept of treating the electric and magnetic fields as 4-vectors via:

$$E_{\alpha}=F_{\alpha\beta}U^{\beta},\:B_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2c}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}F^{\beta\mu}U^{\nu}$$

I wanted to check if $E_{\alpha}$ and $B_{\alpha}$ are spacelike or not. However, when I tried to calculate $E_{\alpha}E^{\alpha}$, I realised that the term $F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$ gives a difference term. Namely, I got:

$$F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}=2\left(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{B}-\frac{1}{c^2}\vec{E}\cdot\vec{E}\right)$$

which may or may not be positive. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you clarify how you obtained a $F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$? I would expect only a $U_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\beta\gamma}U^\gamma$, which is an entirely different quantity.

Comment: Oh I thought I needed to sum over the same quantity. Is this approach incorrect?

Comment: You have a definition for $E_\alpha$. Write $E_\alpha E^\alpha$ and literally replace symbols by their definition in terms of $F$. This is the only calculation you have described in words.

Comment: Following up with @RichardMyers 's comment, you need to use that $F_{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmetric. (Note $E_{\alpha}E^{\alpha}$ must involve contractions with $U^\beta$ (since $E_{\alpha}$ does), whereas $F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$ does not.)

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of problems there. One is *conceptual*, and the other is *notational*.

Conceptually, neither $\boldsymbol{E}$, nor $\boldsymbol{B}$ are 4-vectors. They are the only non-zero components of the tensor $F_{\alpha\beta}$:
$$
F_{\alpha\beta}=\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}-\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}
$$
Where $A^{\alpha}$ is the vector potential.

Notationally, it is convenient to distinguish space-time indices (Greek letters) from space indices in an inertial frame (Latin letters). So that,
$$
E_{i}=F_{0i}
$$
$$
B_{i}=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{0ijk}F_{jk}
$$
(The minus sign can be traced down to the metric.)
So that,
$$
B_{3}=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{321}F_{21}-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{312}F_{12}=F_{21}
$$
etc. (Check me for signs, it's a good exercise.)

Also check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism

You should be able to recover both Maxwell's equations, and the Lorentz force law from all this.

As to the sign of the Lagrangian (that's how it's called). Pick an inertial frame, and calculate:
$$
-\frac{1}{4}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{E}^{2}-\boldsymbol{B}^{2}\right)
$$
Now pick particular solutions of Maxwell's equations in the vacuum (e.g. linearly polarised monochromatic waves). They have the same amplitude: $\boldsymbol{E}_{0}=\boldsymbol{B}_{0}$, but they are out-of-phase by half a cycle. That alone will convince you that this expression is not sign-definite: At some points it's positive, and at others it's negative.
A different case is the electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor:
$$
T^{\alpha\beta}=\eta^{\alpha\nu}F_{\nu\gamma}F^{\gamma\beta}+\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}F_{\gamma\nu}F^{\gamma\nu}
$$
The (zero,zero) component giving you the energy density (frame-dependent):
$$
T^{00}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{E}^{2}+\boldsymbol{B}^{2}\right)
$$
This one is frame-dependent, but positive-definite.

**Note:** $c=1$ throughout.

Comment: From Wald's General Relativity, p.64: "For an observer moving with 4-velocity $v^a$, the quantity $E_a=F_{ab}v^b$ (4.2.21) is interpreted as the electric field measured by that observer,..." .  (Just as $v^b$ is a v-dependent 4-vector, $F^a{}_{b}v^b$ is a v-dependent 4-vector... and this particular v-dependent 4-vector is orthogonal to $v^b$... a purely-spatial vector to $v^b$, which all frames will agree on... Further, in v's frame, $F^a{}_{b}v^b$ has 3 generally-nonzero components.)

Comment: Good point. However, you can always express a non-invariant or non-covariant quantity as the contraction of two invariant (covariant) quantities –except, possibly, non-polynomial ones. E.g., the $x$ coordinate is not an $O\left(3\right)$ scalar in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, even though you can express it in a covariant (scalar) way: $\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}$.